# PostgreSQL 10.5 on Windows 10 invalid locale name

Tags: postgresql, localization

I tried to create a db as below;

```
CREATE DATABASE "postgres"
    WITH OWNER "postgres"
    ENCODING 'UTF8'
    LC_COLLATE = 'en_US.UTF-8'
    LC_CTYPE = 'en_US.UTF-8';
```

But, I received **ERROR:  invalid locale name: "en_US.UTF-8"**

As I supposed to install this locale anyway? If so, how?

Comment: See related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51351191/how-to-create-a-database-with-utf-8-collation-in-postgresql-on-windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on, your operating system.

If you are on some kind of UNIX, run `locale -a` to display all available locales. Then use one of these.

On Windows use `English`.

Comment: Any official documentation on this for Windows?

Comment: @zwcloud Search microsoft.com. I tried for 5 minutes but didn't find anything good.